# Disconnect for WebSocketSubject

Tags: angular, websocket

I have an Angular project in which I want to implement receiving data from the server via a websocket.

To implement the websocket service, I followed the instructions [angular-websocket-starter](https://github.com/AlexDaSoul/angular-websocket-starter)

But this websocket implementation does not have a method to disconnect the socket.
I need the socket to be closed when the component in which it is called is destroyed.
I added a disconnect method for the service, but when the component is destroyed, the socket reconnects and starts working again.

websocket.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable, OnDestroy, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, SubscriptionLike, Subject, Observer, interval } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { WebSocketSubject, WebSocketSubjectConfig } from 'rxjs/webSocket';

import { share, distinctUntilChanged, takeWhile } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { IWebsocketService, IWsMessage, WebSocketConfig } from './websocket.interfaces';
import { config } from './websocket.config';

export const wsUrl = 'wss://example.com:1234';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebsocketService implements IWebsocketService, OnDestroy {

  private config: WebSocketSubjectConfig<IWsMessage<any>>;

  private websocketSub: SubscriptionLike;
  private statusSub: SubscriptionLike;

  private reconnection$: Observable<number>;
  private websocket$: WebSocketSubject<IWsMessage<any>>;
  private connection$: Observer<boolean>;
  private wsMessages$: Subject<IWsMessage<any>>;

  private reconnectInterval: number;
  private reconnectAttempts: number;
  private isConnected: boolean;

  public status: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(@Inject(config) private wsConfig: WebSocketConfig) {
    this.wsMessages$ = new Subject<IWsMessage<any>>();

    this.reconnectInterval = wsConfig.reconnectInterval || 5000; // pause between connections
    this.reconnectAttempts = wsConfig.reconnectAttempts || 10; // number of connection attempts

    this.config = {
      url: wsConfig.url,
      closeObserver: {
        next: (event: CloseEvent) => {
          console.log('WebSocket disconnected!');
          this.websocket$ = null;
          this.connection$.next(false);
        }
      },
      openObserver: {
        next: (event: Event) => {
          console.log('socket event:',event);
          console.log('WebSocket connected!');
          this.connection$.next(true);
        }
      }
    };

    // connection status
    this.status = new Observable<boolean>((observer) => {
      this.connection$ = observer;
    }).pipe(share(), distinctUntilChanged());

    // run reconnect if not connection
    this.statusSub = this.status
    .subscribe((isConnected) => {
      this.isConnected = isConnected;

      if (!this.reconnection$ && typeof(isConnected) === 'boolean' && !isConnected) {
        this.reconnect();
      }
    });

    this.websocketSub = this.wsMessages$.subscribe(
      null, (error: ErrorEvent) => console.error('WebSocket error!', error)
    );

    this.connect();
  }

  disconnect(): void {       // <----I have added this method
    this.websocket$ = null;
    this.wsMessages$.complete();
    this.connection$.next(false);
    this.connection$.complete();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.websocketSub.unsubscribe();
    this.statusSub.unsubscribe();
  }


  /*
   * connect to WebSocked
   * */
  private connect(): void {
    this.websocket$ = new WebSocketSubject(this.config);

    this.websocket$.subscribe(
      (message) => this.wsMessages$.next(message),
      (error: Event) => {
        if (!this.websocket$) {
          // run reconnect if errors
          this.reconnect();
        }
      });
  }


  /*
   * reconnect if not connecting or errors
   * */
  private reconnect(): void {
    this.reconnection$ = interval(this.reconnectInterval)
    .pipe(takeWhile((v, index) => index < this.reconnectAttempts && !this.websocket$));

    this.reconnection$.subscribe(
      () => this.connect(),
      null,
      () => {
        // Subject complete if reconnect attemts ending
        this.reconnection$ = null;

        if (!this.websocket$) {
          this.wsMessages$.complete();
          this.connection$.complete();
        }
      });
  }

  /*
   * on message event
   * */
  public on<T>(event: string): Observable<T> {
    if (event) {
      return this.wsMessages$.pipe(
        filter((message: IWsMessage<T>) => message.event === event),
        map((message: IWsMessage<T>) => message.data)
      );
    }
  }
}
```

The component in which the socket is called:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.websocketService.on<any[]>('messages').subscribe(res => {
      console.log('response from server:',res);
    });
});

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.websocketService.disconnect();  <---this method doesn't work
  }
```

What do I need to change in the service so that the disconnect occurs along with the destruction of the component?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing from the service this line `providedIn: 'root'`

and instead provide it at component level

`@Component({ ..., providers: [WebsocketService] }`

**Update**

Try using `this.websocket$.complete();`

Working demo on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rstkji?file=src/web-socket-consumer/websocket.service.ts)

Comment: It does not change and the disconnect still does not occur.